# How to parse this DateTime in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, date, datetime

How can I parse this String to DateTime in flutter?

```
2023-03-20T14:16:13.7970206+03:00
```

I tried to use `DateTime.parse` however when printing the date of that I get a time difference because of the timezone.

I just to parse it, work with the exact same DateTime and its timezone and later parsing it back to the EXACT same String

```
final datettime = DateTime.parse('2023-03-20T01:46:29.4589214+03:00');
print(datettime); // 2023-03-19 22:46:29.458921Z
```

My Device TimeZone is currently set to US but it should respect the same for all timezones

Comment: yes still the same@pskink

Answer (score 0):

I had to use this package to parse it to the specific timezone

https://pub.dev/packages/timezone

```dart
import 'package:timezone/timezone.dart' as tz;

    final dateTimeParsed = DateTime.parse(dateString);
    final riyadhTimeZone = tz.getLocation('Asia/Riyadh');
    var tzDateTime = tz.TZDateTime.from(dateTimeParsed, riyadhTimeZone);
```